# error during sbt launcher: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: java

So I'm installing CMAK(Cluster Manager for Apache Kafka) and when I run the command

```
sbt clean dist
```

in the terminal, i receive this error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
        at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:425)
        at sbt.TrapExit$.installManager(TrapExit.scala:53)
        at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:127)
        at sbt.xMain$.run(Main.scala:67)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at sbt.internal.XMainConfiguration.run(XMainConfiguration.scala:45)
        at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:39)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$run$1(Launch.scala:149)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:176)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:149)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$apply$1(Launch.scala:44)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:159)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:44)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:21)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:73)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] [launcher] error during sbt launcher: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
```

So I have been trying to fix this all morning, and still not understanding what is really going on here. My current version of dependencies:

```
JDK: 19
JRE: 1.8.0_202
SBT: 1.8.2
```

Help me, please!

Answer (score 8):

It appears that you are running with Java 19 rather than the Java 8 JRE.  (You would not get this error for Java 8.)

The deprecation warning for `SecurityManager` in SBT has been raised as an SBT issue; see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6558.  But that is against Java 17.

In Java 18+ the Java runtime is not just giving a deprecation warning.  The `SecurityManager` class has now been changed to be non-functional; see https://openjdk.org/jeps/411 ... where it talks about the plans for Java 18 and later.

As a result, SBT 1.8.2 and earlier don't work on Java 18 and later.

Your options are:

- Downgrade to Java 17 (or maybe Java 11 or Java 8)
- Upgrade to SBT 1.9.0-RC1 or later ... where SBT's dependency on `SecurityManager` is apparently removed.  (The issue above has been closed as Resolved.)

---

As a general rule, I would recommend people stick with the LTS Java releases; i.e. 8, 11 and 17 (and 21 when it arrives).  The non-LTS releases are EOL'd after 6 months, and 3rd-party software vendors tend not to support them immediately (if at all).  For example the SBT documentation recommends Java 8, 11 or 17.

Comment: Can you provide me with a link to the SBT 1.9.0-RC1 for windows please? Bc all pages that im looking at right now are saying that the latest version of sbt is only 1.8.2

Comment: Go to the Github site.  You may need to build it for yourself.  If that is too hard, use the other option; i.e. use Java 17.

Comment: I found it - https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/download/v1.9.0-RC1/sbt-1.9.0-RC1.msi.  Obviously, if you use an RC rather than a Release, you may experience (new) issues.  If that's too scary, use the Java 17 option instead.

Comment: I tried to install the sbt 1.9.0 version and the problem still persists. I tried to downgrade to jdk 17, the command worked but some new problem arised with CMAK itself. Im so confused right now, not sure what to do next :<

Comment: The new CMAK problem might be an issue caused by using v1.9.0-RC1.  Roll back to 1.8.2 (+ Java 17).

Comment: If people are seeing this using SBT 1.9.0 or later on Java 18 and later, then they should raise a new issue in the SBT issue tracker.

Answer (score 4):

Rerunning the command with this option `-Djava.security.manager=allow` for JRE 17+ worked for me. Like `sbt -Djava.security.manager=allow clean dist`

Got this from the issue reported on the github sbt repo https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6558#issuecomment-1457274792

Comment: That probably will only work for Java 17.  Not Java 18 and later.